# Removing Listeners from components in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have a two way update happening between two of my text fields (NOTE: I do not want to use MVVM binding for this).

**textfield1** updates **textfield2** and vice versa when there is a key press. I need to disable the listeners on the recieving textfield, otherwise I end up in an infinite loop.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'form',

    items: [{
        id: 'tf1',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: '1',
        listeners: {
            change: function() {
                var r = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tf2');
                r[0].setValue(this.getValue() + "!")
            }
        }
    }, {
        id: 'tf2',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: '2',
        listeners: {
            change: function() {
                var r = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tf1');
                r[0].setValue(this.getValue() + "!")
            }
        }

    }]
});
```

Obviously in the above example, if I do a keypress I end up with two textfields with infinite '!' at the end.

Fiddle is here :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ces

I need to disable the listeners. I had a look at '**removeListener**', and I think you would use it like this :

```
        r[0].removeListener('change');
```

However I need a reference to my listener, so I can add it back once the setValue(..) has occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging around a bit, I found out that **suspendEvents** and **resumeEvents** solves my problem.

```
        r[0].suspendEvents();

        r[0].setValue(this.getValue() + "!")

        r[0].resumeEvents();
```

The disable all listeners and re-enable them all.

Comment: Note you can use `suspendEvent` and pass the name to suspend specific events.